# Using header in Highchart in the exporting.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I cannot put a header inside the container div Highchart to export or print (using exporting.js) a chart with additional information. I tried using some appends, but it stay within the limits of div.container and not outside, like:

```
 chart.renderer.image('icons/custom/ERI_UF_rgb.png ', 0, -50, 120, 48).add();
 chart.renderer.text('This is the footer text. limited It has text
                      space based on chart width', 10, 265)
      .css({
          color: '# 4572A7'
          fontSize: '12px '
      })
      .add();
 chart.renderer.text('This is the sub-footer text. Avoid covering 
                      credits text on bottom', 10, 280)
      .css({
          color: '# 4572A7'
          fontSize: '12px '
      })
      .add();
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? I also accept suggestions from libraries that do the printing or export of certain divs.

Comment: The exporting module tends to use the original settings to render the exported chart, so elements you add programmatically will not be included. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848335/highcharts-settitle-ignored-when-exporting-chart) may be of some help. Alternatively, could you provide a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that is possible use spacingTop and spacingBottom like this:

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        spacingTop: 200,
        spacingBottom: 200
    }
```

So, I can putting a header or footer in the charts writting  chart.renderer.image or  chart.renderer.text.

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/LZbDA/

Comment: I was under the impression you were trying to export a chart that included the additional info. While this will provide extra room in the chart, the content that you've added will not appear when exporting.